# Reuse/refactor code inside Angular service

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have an Angular service that gets data via JSON requests and sends the resulting JSON objects to a number of different controllers.

The code below is a snippet of this service.  The `postData` function is an example of one of many different functions inside this service (that all pretty much do the same thing, but just make different requests).  There are other functions in this service named `viewData`, `visitorData`, etc...

```
// Service for making JSON requests
    myApp.factory('getData', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 
      function($http, $cookieStore) {
      return {
        postData: function() {

          // Store shared variables   
          var source = 
            ($cookieStore.get('tab') == '#/dashboard/2') ?
            source = $cookieStore.get('1234') :
            source = $cookieStore.get('5678');
          var month = $cookieStore.get('month'),
              year = $cookieStore.get('year');

          // Derive the number of days in the given month
          var month_days = (new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate();

          // Return the promise
          return $http({
            url: base_url + 'string', 
            method: "GET",

            // Set the proper parameters
            params: { 
              id: source,
              start: year + '-' + month + '-01',
              end: year + '-' + month + '-' + month_days,
              interval: 'day'
              }
          });
        },
        ...
```

The problem I'm facing is that at the beginning of each of these functions, I have to include this chunk of code, **and it's the exact same for each function.**

```
// Store shared variables   
var source = 
  ($cookieStore.get('tab') == '#/dashboard/2') ?
  source = $cookieStore.get('1234') :
  source = $cookieStore.get('5678');
var month = $cookieStore.get('month'),
    year = $cookieStore.get('year');

// Derive the number of days in the given month
var month_days = (new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate();
```

However, it's difficult to just factor it out, because if I do so, when I call the functions, the `source`, `month`, and `year` values don't change along with the updated `$cookieStore` values.  Is there an official way I can have multiple functions within a service share, perhaps a super function that is called every time the functions themselves are called?  Basically-- what's the Angular way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what your getting at, but you could encapsulate your logic in another service and include it in the services that you want it to be used in the dependencies;

```
myApp.factory('getCookieDataSvc', [ '$cookieStore',function($cookieStore){
return {
    getCookieData: function(){
        var source =
            ($cookieStore.get('tab') == '#/dashboard/2') ?
                source = $cookieStore.get('1234') :
                source = $cookieStore.get('5678');
        var month = $cookieStore.get('month'),
            year = $cookieStore.get('year');

        // Derive the number of days in the given month
        var month_days = (new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate();

        return {
            source: source,
            month_days: month_days,
            month: month,
            year: year,
        }
    }
}
});
```

Then you could call it in your other services or controllers like the following:

```
myApp.factory('getData', ['$http', 'getCookieDataSvc', function($http, getCookieDataSvc) {
return {
    postData: function() {
        var cookieData = getCookieDataSvc.getCookieData();

        // Return the promise
        return $http({
            url: base_url + 'string',
            method: "GET",

            // Set the proper parameters
            params: {
                id: cookieData.source,
                start: cookieData.year + '-' + cookieData.month + '-01',
                end: cookieData.year + '-' + cookieData.month + '-' + cookieData.month_days,
                interval: 'day'
            }
        });
    }
}});
```

Comment: Yeah I tried something like this, but it didn't work.  I'm going to try it again.

Answer (score 2):

Make them module level variables and use `'this'` to access them. Example below. Rather than Angular this is the more JavaScript module way to do this.

```
myApp.factory('getData', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 
      function($http, $cookieStore) {
      var factory = {};
      factory.month = ""; // initialize to whatever you want
      factory.year = ""; // initialize to whatever you want

      factory.postData = function() {
           var self = this;
           self.month = $cookieStore.get('month');
           ...
      };

      ...
      ...

      return factory;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values in your cookies are mutable, you can organize your code this way as well to ensure that you always get the latest values from the $cookieStore. This will allow you to contain your `$cookieStore` code in a single function as well.

```
myApp.factory('getData', ['$http', '$cookieStore', 
  function($http, $cookieStore) {

      function getSource() {
        return (getCookieValue('tab') === '#/dashboard/2')
          ? getCookieValue('1234')
          : getCookieValue('5678')
      }

      function getCookieValue(key) {
        return $cookieStore.get(key);
      }

      // Danger ahead, mutations!
      function initValues(source, month, year) {
        source = getSource();
        month = getCookieValue('month');
        year = getCookieValue('year');
      }

      return {
        postData: function() {

          // Store shared variables   
          var source, month, year;
          initValues(source, month, year);

          // Derive the number of days in the given month
          var month_days = (new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate();

          // Return the promise
          return $http({
            url: base_url + 'string', 
            method: "GET",

            // Set the proper parameters
            params: { 
              id: source,
              start: year + '-' + month + '-01',
              end: year + '-' + month + '-' + month_days,
              interval: 'day'
              }
          });
        },
        ...
```